# Modal not selecting current object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this class in React:

```js
render() {
let addedItems = this.props.items.length ? (
  this.props.items.map(item => {
    return (
      <li className="collection-item avatar" key={item.id}>
        <div className="item-desc">
          <Modal trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Editar</Button>}>
            <Header icon="archive" content="Archive Old Messages" />
            <Modal.Content>
              {/* CHEESE */}
              <Button.Group>
                <Link to="/cart">
                  <Button
                    icon="plus"
                    onClick={() => {
                      console.log("BUT +");
                      this.handleCheese(item, "+");
                    }}
                  />
                </Link>
                <Button content="Cheese" labelPosition="left" />
                <Link to="/cart">
                  <Button
                    icon="minus"
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.handleCheese(item, "-");
                      
                    }}
                  />
                </Link>
                <h2>{item.queijo}</h2>
              </Button.Group>
            </Modal.Content>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  })
) 
}
```

In resume a modal should open according to the object I'm selecting.

But in my code the item.id is selecting the last object I inserted in the addedItems.

**I need the modal to have the info about the obj I selected.**

In case you want to see all code is in: https://github.com/fernanda-avelar/burguer_cart ->
This page is the /src/components/Cart.js

Comment: can you provide more info like what button you are clicking and the function definition of the called function.

Comment: I am clicking the Button with the Icon "minus" that shoul decrease the quantity of cheese of that burger/obj. And <h2>{item.queijo}</h2> should show the quantity of cheese in the selected obj but its showing from the last object I added to the addedItems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can have only one modal in your window, that's why it's taking the last one (by having overriden all others).

So instead you should put your modal out of the `.map`.

Also, keep track of the selected item via a controlled state `selectedItem`.

Then use it the the Modal.Content :

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <Modal.Content>
        /* content depending of this.state.selectedItem */
      </Model.Content>
      /* your other stuff */
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I get your Idea but each obj has a button to open the modal. But I think that I can use your Idea. Thank you

Comment: It totally fixed my problem! Thank you